# Dotnet 3.0.103 - JsonConvert.DeserializeObject expects well escaped string as opposed to a plain Json

Tags: c#, jsonconvert

I am on Dotnet 3.0.103. I have exposed a webapi, that has a code defined like this,

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] string data)
        {
            try
            {
            EmployeeRequest request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeRequest>(data);
```

Now, when I call the API from my postman, a normal json request body like this, does not work

```
{"EmployeeId": 3, "Name": "John"}
```

It throws an error like this,

```
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|b9ea70ff-4ffda7ef1c244839."
}
```

Where as an escaped string as opposed to a Json body works fine,

```
 "{\"EmployeeId\": 3, \"Name\": \"John\"}"
```

I would like to make it work with just a plain json.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Just out of curiosity try changing your data variable to an object type [FromBody] object data . Then convert it to a string.

Comment: You'll be better putting the model in to the Action's parameters and letting ASP.Net's model binding take care of the deserialization for you - `public string Post([FromBody]EmployeeRequest request)`.

Comment: Sorry I am extremely new to Dotnet. Should I cast it like this, `[HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] object data)
        {
            try
            {
            EmployeeRequest request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeRequest>((string)data);` When I do this, I get this error `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.String'`

Comment: I agree with @phuzi

Comment: But its not allowing me to cast the body as a string, cannot convert from `'EmployeeApi.EmployeeRequest' to 'string'` This `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeRequest>` seems to expect a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net's model binding can bind a JSON payload to your Action's parameters automatically. As such you should be able to do away with the manual deserialization:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]EmployeeRequest request)
{
    // request should be properly populated
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to separately deserialize the json. .NET can do that for you out of the box. 
Try changing the signature to: `public string Post([FromBody] EmployeeRequest data)`and make the call from postman without escaping. It should work.